# How many expr_no_commas '=' expr_no_commas expressions are there in C?

Tags: c, syntax

```
expr_no_commas '=' expr_no_commas
```

It's found in C's rule,but the only possible form I can think of is:

```
identifier = expr_no_commas
```

that is,the left side is a single variable,any other variants?

Answer (score 5):

There a lot of C expressions that are assignments to non-identifiers; here are a few examples:

```
x[1] = 5;
*f() = 7;
*p++ = 0;
a[i].f = a[i].g;
```

Comment: @assem: Applying the `*` operator to an rvalue pointer returns an lvalue.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you find that "rule"?  The syntax presented in the language standard (draft [n1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), § 6.5.16) is

```
assignment-expression:
    conditional-expression
    unary-expression assignment-operator assignment-expression

assignment-operator: one of
    = *= /= %= += -= >= &= ^= |=
```

where *unary-expression* results in any number of productions that aren't simple identifiers (as Jeremiah Willcock has shown).